# node.js use local variables in imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I'm working on a small project - online game in node.js, learning it at the same time. I started off with one big server file server.js where I did all http, https, socket handling, however, as it began growing in size I figured I should keep my classes and functions in other files. Now I have a file functions.js, which looks like this:

```
//functions.js
//broadcast message to all clients
exports.broadcast = function(msg, wss) {
wss.clients.forEach(function (client) {
 client.send(msg);    
  });
}
```

And the excerpt of interest from server.js is this:

```
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: secureServer});
wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
//a single websocket starts here
  var thisSocket = new ClientSocket(ws);

  ws.on("close", function close() {
  //remove websocket from sockets, but wait 5 seconds to avoid refresh disconnects

  for (var i = 0; i < clientSockets.length; i++) {
  if (clientSockets[i].socket === ws) {
  clientSockets.splice(i, 1);
  break;
  }
  }
  //only inform if disconnected user had username
  if (typeof thisSocket.username != "undefined") {
  var message = {};
  message.type = "disconnected";
  message.username = thisSocket.username;
  functions.broadcast(JSON.stringify(message), wss);
  }
  });
```

Everything works fine, however, my question is - how do I tell the function "broadcast()" to use the local variable wss instead of having to specify in the function call

```
exports.broadcast = function(msg) {
```

Is this possible? Because it would help simplify the code a lot, as in other functions I will have to provide 3, 4 or even more variables to the function, whereas if the function was inside the same file it would only use 1 variable, for example.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not clear about what you're asking. If they're not actually *variable* at the time of the *function call* then why pass them in? Write the function with the values it needs, or write a function generator that closes over the local values you need.

Comment: Inside the file server.js I can just use "wss" inside the function after it's declared, however, if I import the function from another file, I have to explicitly give wss to the function when calling it. Can this be avoided?

Comment: Unrelated, but please try to indent your code; readability is hugely important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `functions.js` a *builder* for the `broadcast` function, like so:

```
//functions.js
//broadcast message to all clients
exports.getBroadcast = function(wss) {
  return function(msg) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function (client) {
      client.send(msg);    
   });
  };
};
```

Then in your app file that imports it:

```
var functions = require('./functions.js');
var broadcast = functions.getBroadcast(wss);
```

Then use `broadcast`, which has `wss` baked into it.

And of course, if `functions.js` has several functions in it that need `wss`, you can define them all in one `get` call.

---

Re your comment:

> I am trying this: var functions = require("./functions.js").getFunctions(wss, clientSockets, gameRooms); var broadcast = functions.broadcast; var broadcastNewClient = functions.broadcastNewClient; var dataOnJoin = functions.dataOnJoin; I get an error "undefined".

That usage should be fine, provided `getFunctions` looks like this:

```
exports.getFunctions = function(wss, clientSockets, gameRooms) {
  return {
    broadcast: function(msg) {
      // ... implementation using `msg` and `wss`...
    },
    broadcastNewClient: function(/*...args...*/) {
      // ... implementation...
    },
    dataOnJoin: function(/*...args...*/) {
      // ... implementation...
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot! However, I still don't understand how the relationships between these variables work. I am trying this:

var functions = require("./functions.js").getFunctions(wss, clientSockets, gameRooms);
var broadcast = functions.broadcast;
var broadcastNewClient = functions.broadcastNewClient;
var dataOnJoin = functions.dataOnJoin;

I get an error "undefined".

Comment: @DarbininkaiBroliai: I've updated -- but as I was, you accepted the answer, so I'm guessing you worked out how to use it that way yourself. :-)

Comment: Thanks. Although I get how this works, the notation is very strange, and different every time for some reason. Thanks again!

Comment: @DarbininkaiBroliai: No worries. I'm not following you about notation...?